# ES6/TS/Angular2 parsing JSON to Date

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have following json:

```
let JSON_RESPONSE = `{"birthDates": ["2017-01-02","2016-07-15"]}`
```

I have a `TypeScript` object with `Date` array declared and a `ES6` featured constructor init:

```
class Children {
  birthDates: Date[] = []

  constructor(values: Object = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, values)
  }
}
```

I want to init this object from JSON output it's days:

```
const children = new Children(JSON.parse(this.JSON_RESPONSE))
children.birthDates.forEach(it => {
  console.log(it.getDate())
})
```

Obviously it doesn't work because `Children#birthDates` are of `Object` type instead of `Date`. And adding explicit `new Date()` initialization helps:

```
children.birthDates.forEach(it => {
  console.log(new Date(it).getDate())
})
```

The question is how to painlessly convert JSON to legit `Date` objects on object's constructor stage without manually mapping every property to the JSON input.

Clearly, `Object.assign` doesn't fit my desires and performs `shallow` copy instead of `deep` with type inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in the constructor to get all values as dates:

```
type Data = {
    birthDates: string[];
}

class Children {
    birthDates: Date[];

    constructor(values?: Data) {
        if (values) {
            this.birthDates = values.birthDates.map(value => new Date(value));
        } else {
            this.birthDates = [];
        }
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Data%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20birthDates%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Children%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20birthDates%3A%20Date%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(values%3F%3A%20Data)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(values)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.birthDates%20%3D%20values.birthDates.map(value%20%3D%3E%20new%20Date(value))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.birthDates%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D))

---

#### Edit

In the case where the data has more fields you can use `Object.assign` and then override the `birthDates` property with the mapped version:

```
interface IChildren {
    size: number;
    groudId: string;
    birthDates: string[];
}

class Children {
    size: number = 0;
    groudId: string = null;
    birthDates: Date[] = [];

    constructor(values?: IChildren) {
        if (values) {
            Object.assign(this, values);
        }

        this.birthDates = this.birthDates.map(value => new Date(value));
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20IChildren%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20size%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20groudId%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20birthDates%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Children%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20size%3A%20number%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20groudId%3A%20string%20%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20birthDates%3A%20Date%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(values%3F%3A%20IChildren)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(values)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.assign(this%2C%20values)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.birthDates%20%3D%20this.birthDates.map(value%20%3D%3E%20new%20Date(value))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D))

Comment: What if I have another field in my model? Let say of `string` type? Number of `if` will be increased exponentially with every field added, won't it?

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot! The only minor downside is `birthDates` set twice as I understand. But I can live with it.

Comment: It is actually set 3 times but to change that you'll need to add more code which will raise the question "is it worth it?"

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed a default init with `[]`.